# GroupBy Multiple Tables Using Foreign Key

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, group-by

I have two tables, and I calculate Post Views from `Views` table using `ViewDate` column and then I want to get `PostTItle` using `.GroupBy` for Entity Framework using foreign key `PostID`.

`Posts` table:

```
PostID   PostTitle
--------------------
1         post one
2         post two 
3         post three
4         post four
5         post five
6         post six
```

`Views` table:

```
ViewID     ViewDate             PostID   
---------------------------------------
  1        2015 07 17 19:00:00        1
  2        2015 07 17 20:00:00        1
  3        2015 07 17 21:00:00        2
  4        2015 07 18 19:00:00        2
  5        2015 07 19 19:00:00        2
  6        2015 07 21 19:00:00        1
  7        2015 07 23 19:00:00        2
```

**so far this is what I have done**

```
    return _db.ObjectSet.Where(p => DateTime.Now >= EntityFunctions.AddDays(p.ViewDate, -14))
        .GroupBy(y => y.PostID, y => y.ViewDate, (ID, Date) => new ExampleViewModel
        {
            Post_ID = ID,
            View_Date = Date.Count()
        }).OrderByDescending(z => z.View_Date).Take(5);
```

but using this solution I can only assign `Post_ID` and `View_Date` to `ExampleViewModel`, How can I get the `PostTitle` using the foreign key?

**Note: I am trying to get most viewed (Hot) Posts in last 14 days**

Please help

**Expected Output:**

```
Title:post one, Id:1, Views:3
Title:post two, Id:2, Views:4
```

Comment: Do you have an one to many relationship represented in your model between `View` and `Post` entities?

Comment: @octavioccl: Only one relationship, `PostID` is the relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be applying a `join` between those entities and include the `PostTitle` in the fields you want to group:

```
var query= (from v in db.Views
            join p in db.Posts on v.PostID equals p.Id
            where  DbFunctions.DiffDays(v.ViewDate,DateTime.Now)<=14
            group new{v,p} by new {v.PostID, p.PostTitle, v.ViewDate} into g
            let count=g.Count()
            orderby count descending
            select new{ Post_ID=g.Key.PostID, View_Date=count, Title= g.Key.PostTitle}
           ).Take(5);
```

As you can see, I'm using `DbFunction` class instead `EntityFunction`. The `DbFunctions` class was introduced in Entity Framework 6 and it is shipped separately from the .NET Framework. For any new applications using versions of EF starting with 6.0, you should use the `DbFunctions` class. Anyway, if you don't want to use now that class, you could also use the `EntityFunctions.DiffDays` method.

Now if both entities are related:

```
public class Post
{
  public int ID{get;set;}
  // ...
  public virtual ICollection<View> Views{get;set;}
}
public class View
{
  public int ID{get;set;}

  public int PostID{get;set;}
  // ...
  public virtual Post Post{get;set;}
}
```

You could also do this:

```
var query= (from v in db.Views
            where  DbFunctions.DiffDays(v.ViewDate,DateTime.Now)<=14
            group v by new {v.PostID, v.ViewDate} into g
            let count=g.Count()
            orderby count descending
            select new{ Post_ID=g.Key.PostID, View_Date=count, Title= g.First().Post.PostTitle}
           ).Take(5);
```

### Update 1

To avoid use `EntityFunctions` class you can subtract 14 days to the current date and compare directly both dates in your query:

```
 var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);
 var query= (from v in db.Views
             join p in db.Posts on v.PostID equals p.Id
             where  v.ViewDate>=date
             group new{v,p} by new {v.PostID, p.PostTitle, v.ViewDate} into g
             let count=g.Count()
             orderby count descending
             select new{ Post_ID=g.Key.PostID, View_Date=count, Title= g.Key.PostTitle}
         ).Take(5);
```

### Update 2

That is because you're grouping by date. To obtain the result you're expecting you need to remove that field from the elements you are grouping:

```
  var query= (from v in db.Views
              join p in db.Posts on v.PostID equals p.Id
              where  v.ViewDate>=date
              group new{v,p} by new {v.PostID, p.PostTitle} into g
              let count=g.Count()
              orderby count descending
              select new{ Post_ID=g.Key.PostID, View_Date=count, Title= g.Key.PostTitle}
             ).Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually this web application was made in EF4, and they also have made web services, and apps for the site. I tried to talk to them to move to EF6 and MVC5 but they said not we want to be on EF4 and MVC3 for some more time. new requirement was to get the Hot Posts in 7 Days, in 14 Days, or in a Month. So I can't really use EF6 for this but will try your solution now.

Comment: I am getting this error with this solution when I use `EntityFunctions.DiffDays` because it's on EF4, "`{"Method 'System.Nullable 1[System.Int32] DiffDays(System.Nullable 1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable 1[System.DateTime]) has no supported translation to SQL."}`" and same when I use `EntityFunctions.AddDays`.. please reply

Comment: Yes, that should be because you're using an older version of EF 4, I tested both in EF 6+ and they worked.I thought  `AddDays` worked for you in the past, because in that case you could do this: `p.ViewDate>= EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -14)`, What version of EF are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using EF4 because it's client requirement.

Comment: @Rabia, check the uptade 1

Comment: I am getting error 'This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.' and I have updated my question with the function you proposed. Please check where I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Did you see my last solution, in the update 1 section avoiding use the `EntityFunctions` class?

Comment: Yest I just updated with question with your solution in Update 1 without using `EntityFunctions`, but results are not as I expected. Please check. Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working as expected. you are really a life save. God bless!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `Posts` table on your context you can retrieve it from there by the `PostId`:

```
return _db.ObjectSet.Where(p => DateTime.Now >= EntityFunctions.AddDays(p.ViewDate, -14))
        .GroupBy(y => y.PostID, y => y.ViewDate, (ID, Date) => new ExampleViewModel
        {
            Post_ID = ID,
            View_Date = Date.Count(),
            Title = _db.Posts.Find(ID).PostTitle
        }).OrderByDescending(z => z.View_Date).Take(5);
```

Comment: No unfortunately that's the `context` of `Views` table. So I can't access it like that. But `Foreign Key` is there in `Views` table, I have to use it to get to `PostTitle`. Please reply

Comment: Why don't you have all your tables in the same context?

Comment: @Nimrand: Because I am using class libraries as Data Access Layer. and using `Repositories`. To keep Data Access layer separate.on this `Model` I just called in the `ViewRepository` to access `Views` table and `Foreign Key` should automatically give access to `Posts` table.

Comment: Which class is your method in now? A repository? Can you post your contexts definitions? If `Posts` is not available in that scope you should make it available either on the context or by providing another context or repository there. I can recommend using one context for a related work-flow and just add the stuff you need so you can access it.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers I agree with Erwin.  All related tables should be in the same context.  I might also suggest reviewing design patterns for Repositories and Unit of Work.  There are a lot of ways programmers often get these wrong, and it sounds like you may have coded yourself into a corner for that very reason.